# Convert binary variable from having int values to string values in r

Tags: r, variables, binary

My dependent variable looks like this:

$ dpnm     : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

And I want to convert the 1s int "Yes" and the 0s into "No"

I have tried:

```
default$dpnm <- revalue(default$dpnm , c(1 = "Yes"))
default$dpnm <- revalue(default$dpnm , c(0 = "No"))
```

Comment: Maybe its good to store binary values as a logical vector with `TRUE` and `FALSE`. `default$dpnm <- default$dpnm == 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you can use boolean indexing:

```r
default$dpnm[default$dpnm==0]  <- "No"
default$dpnm[default$dpnm==1]  <- "Yes"
```

Depending on what you are doing, it may make more sense to convert it to an ordered `factor` with labels:

```r
default$dpnm  <- factor(
    default$dpnm, 
    levels = c(0,1), 
    labels = c("No", "Yes"),
    ordered = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Your code works, but it looks risky to me, because the first line `default$dpnm[default$dpnm==0]  <- "No"` changes the type of the column to character.  That means the second line is comparing a character vector to a number in `default$dpnm==1`.  As it happens, this gives the right answer, but I'd worry there are obscure cases of similar problems where it fails (e.g. because of rounding in the conversion).  I'd recommend creating a new intermediate variable rather than modifying the column twice.

Comment: @user2554330 fair point - I think it is OK in a simple case like this but implicit type coercion is certainly worth keeping in mind. I'd be interested if you could find an example where it causes unexpected results.

Comment: There probably aren't any such cases, I just like to avoid code that makes me worry :-).